# Soap Request Format when using Savon in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, soap, savon

I am dealing with a soap api which offers the following as an example of how the request XML should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsg="http://tempuri.org/wsGenRateEstimate/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <RateEstimateRequestVO>
         <Token>7e2c61c4-8b4c-4d8b-b47f-ed033c6f4307</Token>
         <CustomerNumber>1</CustomerNumber>
         <OriginCity>Dothan</OriginCity>
         <OriginState>AL</OriginState>
         <OriginZip>36303</OriginZip>
         <OriginCountryCode>USA</OriginCountryCode>
         <DestinationCity>Atlanta</DestinationCity>
         <DestinationState>GA</DestinationState>
         <DestinationZip>30303</DestinationZip>
         <DestinCountryCode>USA</DestinCountryCode>
         <WhoAmI>S</WhoAmI>
         <BillDate>050415</BillDate>
         <CODAmount></CODAmount>
         <CODPayType></CODPayType>
         <CODFeePaidBy></CODFeePaidBy>
         <FullCoverage>Y</FullCoverage>
         <FullCoverageAmount>32545</FullCoverageAmount>
         <PrePaidCollect></PrePaidCollect>
         <TotalPalletCount></TotalPalletCount>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <AccLine>
            <AccCode></AccCode>
         </AccLine>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <RateEstimateRequestLine>
            <Weight>122</Weight>
            <Class>70</Class>
            <HandlingUnits></HandlingUnits>
            <HandlingUnitType></HandlingUnitType>
            <Hazmat></Hazmat>
            <CubeU></CubeU>
            <Length></Length>
            <Height></Height>
            <Width></Width>
         </RateEstimateRequestLine>
      </RateEstimateRequestVO>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below is the code I am using to attempt this request in rails (covering up my access token for privacy's sake):

```
require 'savon'
client = Savon.client({ wsdl: "http://wsportal.aaacooper.com:8188/wsGenRateEstimate.wsdl" })
# this part is to check what the XML I am sending will look like
request = client.build_request(:ws_gen_rate_estimate, message: { Token: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", OriginCity: "Birmingham", OriginState: "AL", OriginZip: "35222", OriginCountryCode: "USA", DestinationCity: "New Orleans", DestinationState: "LA", DestinationZip: "70122", DestinCountryCode: "USA", CustomerNumber: "000971733", WhoAmI: "S", PrePaidCollect: "" })
# This will actually send the xml to the server api
response = client.call(:ws_gen_rate_estimate, message: { Token: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", OriginCity: "Birmingham", OriginState: "AL", OriginZip: "35222", OriginCountryCode: "USA", DestinationCity: "New Orleans", DestinationState: "LA", DestinationZip: "70122", DestinCountryCode: "USA", CustomerNumber: "000971733", WhoAmI: "S", PrePaidCollect: "" })
render json: {
  "this is a": "test",
  "client_request": request.body,
  "client_response": response.body,
}, status: :ok
```

The response to this request has an "error_message" saying my Token is invalid, however I know I have a valid token, and I know that it is pasted in full in the code there. Here is what the XML looks like being sent to the server:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
     <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:tns=\"http://tempuri.org/wsGenRateEstimate/\" xmlns:env=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
        <env:Body>
           <tns:RateEstimateRequestVO>
              <token>XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX</token>
              <originCity>Birmingham</originCity>
              <originState>AL</originState>
              <originZip>35222</originZip>
              <originCountryCode>USA</originCountryCode>
              <destinationCity>New Orleans</destinationCity>
              <destinationState>LA</destinationState>
              <destinationZip>70122</destinationZip>
              <destinCountryCode>USA</destinCountryCode>
              <customerNumber>000971733</customerNumber>
              <whoAmI>S</whoAmI>
              <prePaidCollect></prePaidCollect>
            </tns:RateEstimateRequestVO>
        </env:Body>
     </env:Envelope>
```

The tag names and namespaces are different than the example asks for. Could this cause the API to not find the token? If so, does the savon gem provide options to change tag names or attributes?

Comment: Yes, that is the reazon, try using `namespace: 'my_namespace/url'` when initializing `Savon.client`. If it is still not working, try adding `element_form_default: :qualified` as well. I had this problem months ago and I'm not sure which solution solved it.

Comment: I see that the node in your produced request is `token` whereas in the description seems to be `Token`, I think that is solved with `convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase` in your `Savon.client` initialization.

Comment: Thanks byrdEmannuel. The camelcase option fixed it!

Comment: Glad it worked! I will write it as an answer to help more people in the same problem.

Comment: I will accept it as the answer if you post it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node that your Savon is producing is called `token` whereas the service is expecting to receive `Token` (with capital `T`). As you can see, all the nodes have the same problem: they are sent with the initial letter in lowercase and they are expected to be received in uppercase.

Savon [by default](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html) will convert keys to lowerCamelcase. You can change this behavior in the global `convert_request_keys_to`.

The options to this global are `:camelcase`, `:lower_camelcase`, `:upcase` and `:none`.
In your problem, you should use `:camelcase`.

```
require 'savon'
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "http://wsportal.aaacooper.com:8188/wsGenRateEstimate.wsdl",
  convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase
)
```

This way, you can send your request as:

```
request = client.build_request(:ws_gen_rate_estimate, message: { token: "XXXXX", origin_city: "Birmingham" })
```

And the keys will be converted to its corresponding camelcase. Note that you can write them in `snakecase` and will be transformed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This might help as it worked for me following `railscasts`

`Gyoku.convert_symbols_to :camelcase`

For example:

```
def initialize(test)
  Gyoku.convert_symbols_to :camelcase
  client = Savon::Client.new("wsdl_link")
  response = client.request :web, :get_actions, body: { "test" => test }
  if response.success?
  // enter code
  end
end
```